# Testing list against list

Tags: python, list

I know there are other threads with list vs. list, but they don't seem to address my issue. I'm trying to test a series of lists against one specific list and check to see how similar they are. For example,

The "answer key" is as follows:

```
answerkey = "B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
lanswerkey = list[answerkey]
```

and I'm trying to test a series of other lists I am importing, that have the format:

```
N00000023,,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,,C,,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A
N00000024,C,C,D,D,C,B,,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,,C,B,D,A,C,A,B,B,,D
```

Could I do something like this?:

```
right = 0
counter3 = 0
for line in f:   
if lanswerkey.split(",")[counter3] == line.split(",")[counter3]:
   right += 4
if lanswerkey.split(",")[counter3] != line.split(",")[counter3]:
   right -= 1
counter3 += 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your measurment of 'similar'?

Comment: @DisplayName Sorry, I meant testing one against the other for accuracy, in this case "answerkey" are the right answers, and the other lists are what I'm testing against "answerkey" to later calculate a grade

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is the exact logic you want to use to compare two lists?

Comment: @DisplayName For example, if the 3rd item in "answerkey" is "B", and the 3rd item in another one of the lists is "C", it would be incorrect. As if to grade a multiple choice exam.

Answer (score 2):

In numpy you can easily compare two arrays with symbol `==`, the only problem is you need two arrays with the same length, you can easily deal with this by setting your own rule. In your case, the `answerkey` has 25 elements and the `line1` has just 22 elements, so you can not compare with them, please set a rule by yourself.

```
import numpy as np

answerkey = "B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
line1  = "N00000023,,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,,C,,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A"
line2 = "N00000024,C,C,D,D,C,B,,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,,C,B,D,A,C,A,B,B,,D"

# convert your lists to numpy array
answer = np.array(list(answerkey.split(",")))
q1 = np.array(list(line1.split(","))[1:]) # [1:] just to get rid of the "N00000023"
q2 = np.array(list(line2.split(","))[1:])

# print your array length to check whether they are comparable
print len(answer), len(q1), len(q2)
>> 25 22 25

# get your result array
res = answer == q2
>> [False False  True  True  True  True False  True  
   True  True  True  True True  True False  True  True  
   True  True  True  True False  True False True]

# calculate your score
score = sum(res)*4 - (len(res)-sum(res))

print score
>> 70
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
answerkey =           "B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
answer    = "N00000024,B,B,D,D,C,A,D,A,C,D,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
# different              ^       ^       ^
```

you can get the number of different positions like this:

```
len([x for x in zip(answerkey.split(","), answer.split(",")[1:]) if x[0] != x[1]])
# result 3
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I get rid of the "N00000024" at the beginning of my lists in this case?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Use `[1:]` to not consider the first item from the list.

Comment: @DisplayName The first entry in the user's list `N00000023,,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,,C,,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A` doesn't have the same length as the `answer_key`.

Comment: What would be the result in this case? How do the missing letters count to the score?

Comment: Missing answers will be treated like wrong answers in your approach, I think this is correct behaviour.

Comment: @DisplayName I seem to be running into issues with the "[1:]" method. When I print: 

print([x for x in zip(answerkey.split(","), line.split(",")[1:]) if x[0] != x[1]])

I get the right amount of items:

[('B', 'N00000045'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'A'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('C', ''), ('D', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('C', ''), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('D', 'B')]

When I add the [1:], it seems to throw it off: 

[('B', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', ''), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'A'), ('A', '')]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get a list of answer from answer key.

```
>>> answerkey = answerkey.split(",")
['B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B',
'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D']
```

Then read the answer:

```
>>> answer = raw_input().split(",")[1:]
N00000023,,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,,C,,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A
['', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', '', 'C', '', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A']
```

Lastly, compare the answer:

```
for i in range(len(answerkey)):
  if answerkey[i] == answer[i]:
     right += 4
  else
     right -= 1
```

If you don't want to use for loop, you may take a look at **numpy** library which provided the function of element wise comparsion.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html#numpy.equal

Comment: for numpy one, to get a score you want, just use:  
`result = equal(a,b)`  
`score = sum(result) * 5 - len(result)`